# convert neo4j database to json file using PHP

Tags: php, json, neo4j

I want to know how can I do to convert neo4j database to json file using PHP.

I used the code below but i want to know the similar of mysqli_fetch_assoc in Neo4j:

```
$req= "match n return n"; 
$result = $client->sendCypherQuery($req)->getResult(); //create an array 
$emparray[] = array(); 
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { $emparray[] = $row; } 
echo json_encode($emparray); //write to json file 
$fp = fopen('data/charlize.json', 'w'); 
fwrite($fp, json_encode($emparray));
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Can you give us more details please? How big is your database? how many relationships do you have?

Comment: It's a just small database with just 5 nodes and 5 relationships.

Answer (score 0):

to get all of your database as a JSON you can simply send a post request to `http://<your database ip>/db/data/cypher` with param `"query" : "Match a return a"` this will return a JSON string as response, then you can do whatever you want (print it in a file for example).

Comment: But i want to save the result in json file which is located in a specific folder

Comment: so simply use `fopen`, `fwrite` and `fclose` like you did in your comment. and write the JSON string into the file

Comment: I used the code below but I want to know how i can get json file:

 <script type="text/javascript">     
         var config = {
             dataSource: 'data/charlize.json',
             };
    
   POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher 
   {
    "query" : "Match n return n"
   }
  Accept: application/json; charset=UTF-8
  Content-Type: application/json
    </script>

Comment: Could you please help me @Supamiu